# Syntax help on window.location.hash

Tags: syntax, hash

I am looking for the correct syntax to detect a specific hash value in order to fire a function. Something like:

if (window.location.hash = 'this') {
Do This
}

Thanks. I've have success with detecting an unspecified hash using the following, however I want to be more succinct.

if (!!window.location.hash) {
Do This
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

window.location.hash returns "#this" so you need to remove the hash character before performing the string comparison.

Here's what I've used...

```
var hash = escape(window.location.hash.replace( /^#/, '')); // escape used to prevent injection attacks

if (hash == 'this') {
    doSomethingWithThis();
}
```

Comment: If this answered your question, you should consider accepting is as "correct" by clicking on the "tick" icon on the left.